# Entering a horizontal tab character with protractor.sendKeys / selenium.sendKeys

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

We're currently running into a snag when trying to validate a TSV's input into our application, wherein we try to type the contents of the TSV in using protractor.sendKeys (which relies internally on selenium.sendKeys), however it appears that when selenium sees the `\t` character, it thinks it needs to *literally* press the Tab key, instead of input a horizontal tab `\0x09`.

We've since tried to use protractor.key.Chord with `Alt-0,9` to emulate the Alt code for a horizontal tab, however this results in a single space being entered apparently.  Providing `\u0009` results in a literal tab keypress as well.

Outside of using the browser clipboard (which is currently unavailable to us, due to project constraints), are there any other solutions?

Comment: does the sending the contents of the TSV, character by character as if the user is typing it, does it mimic the typical user experience?

I ask this because, from a User perspective, pressing tab always changes "selected element".

Or would a user simply paste the text in the input?

Comment: We're expecting the user to paste the TSV in, not enter it completely.  Unfortunately, we cannot rely on the system clipboard for our end-to-end tests due to issues we've discovered with using the clipboard in Chrome Headless.

Comment: I'd have 1 suggestion then: try to keep the scenario closer to mimicking a real user interaction and edit the question, put a code example on how you're trying to achieve the "from clipboard" approach and an example of how it's flaky on headless mode.

Comment: I don't see the issue here since `SendKeys` is supposed to simulate a user interacting with the keyboard. What are you trying to simulate? A drop of text? A past from the clipboard?

Comment: Posting as comment because not tested: perhaps replace all occurances with slash tab? i.e. `String tabFriendly = rawData.replace(Keys.TAB, "/" + Keys.TAB);` or possibly `String tabFriendly = rawData.replace(Keys.TAB, "/t");`  (Just realized Javascript was tagged, not Java, but hopefully is still helpful)